# how to pass a pointer to array of strings (char *p[]) ?

Tags: c, cstring

I want to process an Array of strings, so it is an array of an array of chars

I've defined the strings like that

```
char que1[4][LEN_STRING]={{'\0'}};
```

and I want to pass them to the function

```
void print_results(char *pqueries[],document p_docs[]);
```

using a simple

```
  print_results(que1,indoc);
```

results in an " expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'char ( *)[30]' "

I am not even sure ive defined the function signature corrent actually,

help will be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: `char *p[]` is not "pointer to array of strings". It is an array of pointers of char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of arrays is not the same as an array of pointers.  See the C FAQ more details: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/pass2dary.html.

One solution is to modify your function to take fixed-width strings:

```
void print_results(char (*pqueries)[LEN_STRING],document p_docs[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

since it is an array of an array of chars , you can decay it to 
            an array of pointer(each pointer representing the location of the char array)
            and hence use this : char **que1;

```
 for(int z = 0;z<4;z++)
        {
           *que1[z] = malloc(LEN_STRING*(sizeof(char));
           memset(que1[z], '\0', (size_t)LEN_STRING);

         }
```

you can now call this :

```
print_results(que1,indoc);
```

definition of  print_results(que1,indoc) will be :

```
void print_results(char **pqueries,document p_docs[]);
{

//access *[pqueries] in a for loop for each stored character


}
```

rgds,
softy

Answer (score 0):

A correct declaration/definition will be

```
void print_results(char pqueries[][LEN_STRING],document p_docs[]);
void print_results(char pqueries[][LEN_STRING],document p_docs[])
{
  ...
  sprintf(pqueries[0],"%.*s",LEN_STRING-1,"blah0");
  ...
  sprintf(pqueries[3],"%.*s",LEN_STRING-1,"blah3");
}
```